# ddev-ssh-agent fails to start "entry.sh: no such file or directory"

Tags: docker, ddev

I have several DDEV machine on my Linux MINT 20.2 / BTRFS system file , and it was working great. But after a reboot , i cant start my DDEV machine anymore, i have a ddev-ssh-agent error:

> ERROR: for ddev-ssh-agent Cannot start service ddev-ssh-agent: OCI runtime create failed: > container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/entry.sh": stat > /entry.sh: no such file or directory: unknown

thanks

Comment: I imagine you have corrupted docker images.  Try deleting all your containers and images. `ddev poweroff && docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq) && docker rmi -f $(docker images -q)` - This doesn't delete any databases or anything, just containers and images, so when you `ddev start` it will have to pull fresh ones.

Comment: I did that already, I dont have the "/entry.sh" error anymore, but i still have a "ddev-ssh-agent" error:
Failed to start hermitage: failed to start ddev-ssh-agent: ComposeCmd failed to run 'COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=ddev-blablabla docker-compose -f /home/gregory/.ddev/.ssh-auth-compose-full.yaml -p ddev-ssh-agent up --build --force-recreate -d', action='[-p ddev-ssh-agent up --build --force-recreate -d]', err='exit status 1', stdout='Step

Comment: I have also this error : Service 'ddev-ssh-agent' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c (groupadd --gid $gid "$username" || groupadd "$username" || true) && (useradd  -l -m -s "/bin/bash" --gid "$username" --comment '' --uid $uid "$username" || useradd  -l -m -s "/bin/bash" --gid "$username" --comment '' "$username" || useradd  -l -m -s "/bin/bash" --gid "$gid" --comment '' "$username")' returned a non-zero code: 9

Comment: What ddev version? If not v1.18.0, please upgrade. Please show the output of `id -a` as well. Before v1.18.0, numeric usernames and groupnames and usernames with umlauts had trouble like this.

Comment: I'm using 20.10.9

Answer (score 2):

I've successfully solved that problem, mainly by cleaning everything with the following commands:

```
ddev poweroff
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rmi $(docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q --no-trunc)
docker rmi -f $(docker images -q)
docker volume rm ddev-ssh-agent_dot_ssh ddev-ssh-agent_socket_dir
```

(Maybe the last command is enough to solve the problem.)

And then DDEV start.

Comment: This whole problem was the result of a failed system filesystem restore though, see https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues/3306